# Has anyone figured out how to use KSQLDB with AWS GLUE Schema Registry?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-glue, ksqldb, aws-msk

We're trying to use AWS MSK (managed Kafka), and we want to use AWS GLUE Schema registry with AVRO rather than Confluent Schema Registry.

We have brought up KSQLDB, and connected that to MSK, but it needs ksql.schema.registry.url and all that is provided by GLUE is an arn.

Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: Last I checked, KSQL can only use Confluent's Schema Registry.

Comment: That's my guess too, I'm hoping someone has figured out some magic...

Comment: Maybe the `VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'` option, for example, is extensible? I've not looked deeply into it. But then you'd need a way to add arbitrary serializer 
 properties to every possible format.